# My prefix is on a roll

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

An affix riddle:

My prefix is on a roll.
My infix is not on board.
My suffix isn't so sure.

My prefix, infix, and suffix all rhyme, but you'll have to know why.

Where am I?

Hint (modified):

> You can find me on a globe.

Hint 2:

> I suppose this hint might unlock something central to where I am.

Comment: @JLee - Hint added, but please let me know if it's still too vague.

Comment: @Jlee - New hint added.

Comment: When Tom asks for help, you know it's not an easy one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you in

> PANAMA  ?

Updated reasoning thanks to op - my original reasoning is below, but here is the correct interpretation:

> "You'll have to 'know why' clues that the definitions for the prefix, infix, and suffix all clue words which rhyme, but need the last 'y' dropped to form the final word:
>  My prefix is on a roll: PAY - Y = PA
>  My infix is not on board: NAY - Y = NA
>  My suffix isn't so sure: MAY - Y = MA
>  Together we get 'PANAMA'!

Original reasoning:

My prefix is on a roll.

> "On a roll" can mean "employed, being paid, collecting salary."  "PA, or "per annum" is a way of indicating one is being paid and collecting salary on an annual basis.  So the prefix is "PA".

My infix is not on board.

> "NA" could be an abbreviation for "Not applicable/not available", meaning I am not on board with something where normally one might request a "Yes" to indicate being on board. It could also simply be a homophone for "Nah", also a negative response to a request to be on board with something.

My suffix isn't so sure.

> The suffix is "MA". I am also not sure about this; my best guess at this time is that it is a homophone for "Meh", which is an excellent response to something you are not so sure about. E.g. "Would you like to go see that movie?" "Meh; I guess, if I have to. But I'm also fine skipping it."

My prefix, infix, and suffix all rhyme, but you'll have to know why.

> PA, NA, MA rhyme if you pronounce them the same.  Not sure why I'd have to know that.

Hints:
You can find me on a globe.

> PANAMA is on a globe.

I suppose this hint might unlock something central to where I am.

> PANAMA is an *isthmus* in *Central* America, and this hint is an acrostic for "I S T H M U S ctwia".

Where am I?

> This puts you in PANAMA!

Comment: rot 13(Tbg vg, nygubhtu abg dhvgr gur jnl V jnf guvaxvat!  V fhccbfr gur "ab jul" zvtug unir orra n ovg bs n fgergpu.  V jnf guvaxvat cnlebyy, anl, naq znl. Cnl, znl, naq anl eulzr, ohg qebc gur l gb trg cnanzn.)

Comment: I considered this months ago, but just couldn't make it work. Good job +1

Answer (score 1):

Is the answer:

> Jambu Swami Digamber

Because:

> Jam is found on a roll, you swam if you were not "on board", and "amber" as in an amber light can mean unsure if you dating. If you remove "er" from amber you are left with "amb", which rhymes with the other two.

How I found this answer:

> Guessed jam and swam, put "jamA*swamA*" in nutrimatic to receive Jambuswami, and then checked on Google and Google Maps for place names containing Jambuswami or Jambu Swami

Comment: Interesting approach!  But it’s not the intended solution.

Answer (score 1):

Is the Answer:

> Mississippi

Reasoning:

> Missi+Sissy+Iffy.
>  Missi: Missi Roti is a type of Indian roll or bread.
>  Sissy: meaning Cowardly = interpreted here as always backing away or not being on board.
>  Iffy: meaning Doubtful = not sure